# PHP SOAP-ERROR Encoding: object has no X property

Tags: php, soap-client

Creating an instance of SoapClient with a valid wsdl, then calling the service with some broken schema results in a uncatchable fatal error. I would have expected a SoapFault to be raised. Any way to prevent this fatal error (other than always passing the valid request)?

```
Fatal error: SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'X' property
```

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting to say the least...

Adding `xdebug_disable();` right before the service call results in the error being raised as a catchable SoapFault!

Answer (score 0):

Please test it with soapUI first and let me know the error.

Problem lies in the code and more specifically in the sequence and syntax of the arguments passed to the WSDL.